# How to populate data in a JComboBox?

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, jcombobox

I have created a GUI and have a database located externally in which I fetch data from. I am using the GUI builder in NetBeans to do this. Does anyone know of a simple way to populate a jComboBox with values coming from the database? When I run the project there are no errors but the combo box remains empty.

Here is the code that sets the combo box with the names of discounts:

```
public void setDiscountNames(String type, JComboBox cbox) {        
    cbox.removeAllItems();     
    ArrayList<Discount> names = new ArrayList<Discount>();
    try {        
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;            
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abpp034?user=abpp034&password=120001772");
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Name FROM Discount WHERE Type = \"" + type + "\"");
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

     while(rs.next()){                     
         cbox.addItem(rs.getString("Name")); 
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Model.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}
```

This is located in a seperate class from the jComboBox object. This class is called Model.

Here is the place I call the setDiscountNames method in a form called DiscountGUIView:

```
private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                           
     model.setDiscountNames("Fixed", jComboBox1);
}
```

Okay (Update) the query does print the results:

```
run:
```

Travel Standard
Fixed Standard
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Comment: Are you sure that the query is returning results?

Comment: Yeah I'm very sure it is because I run this sql query on the server where my database is located and it retrieved the results successfully.

Comment: But what about your program?  Is it retriving results?  Try adding a `System.out.println` statement in `rs.next` `while-loop`...

Comment: Use `MutableComboBoxModel.addElement` when trying to add item dynamically to the combobox

Comment: Okay so I did the system.out.print and this is the error I recieved:

Comment: Oh wait ignore my comment that was due to a change I made in my code which was mentioned by nmavelichev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: This is your basic mistake.. you're calling the method in ActionPerformed !!

```
classConstructor(){
setDiscountNames("Fixed", jComboBox1); // call this method here.. This will work.

}
```

If the values are printing correctly then try this..

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
while(rs.next()){

     strings.add(rs.getString("Name"));  // Confirm if "Name" is valid


    }
cbox.addItem(strings);
```

Comment: 1- This makes a better comment; 2- `Vector` is generally discouraged in favor of `List` and even in a multithreaded environment, `Collections.synchronizedList` is generally the preferred mechanism

Comment: I've been living my life a lie !! Damn .. My teacher told me to always use a Vector ... Can you please elaborate as why is Vector discouraged in favor of list ?

Comment: `Vector` is generally discouraged in favor of `List` as `List` doesn't make assumptions about the implementation (it is an `interface`), this allows you to make better decisions about how to implement the list (using a `ArrayList` for random access or `LinkedList` for sequential access for example). `Vector` is thread-safe by default, this has performance implications which you shouldn't need to care about if your list is been access by multiple threads.  The Collections API allows you to make decisions about this as you need, allowing you to gain performance improvements

Comment: +1 So vector being thread safe by default has performance drawback as compared to list .. ?

Comment: That's the basic jist.  `Vector` is also a implementation of `List` which has other considerations that might or might not be detrimental to the performance of your application.  The other `List` implementations provide you choices about how the underlying implementation works and which is more suitable for your given situation...

Comment: I have tested the query through a system.print and it turns out the result set does return me the names of discounts.

Comment: However I have the problem on getting these to show on my JComboBox

Comment: edited my Answer @ JP24 .. for the love of Java if the values are not printing in the println, then they won't be added in the JComboBox..

Comment: Are the values which you wana add .. printing in system.put.println(); ? Sounds to me that your values are not printing.. because their is no magic in populating a JComboBox !!

Comment: @Sharpedge run:
[Travel Standard, Fixed Standard]
[Travel Standard, Fixed Standard]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds) Sorry for not being specific earlier so this prints out there should be exactly 2 items in the list Travel Standard and Fixed Standard but what I find funny is that these values are printed out repeatedly

Comment: @ JP24 check my edit I just made ... you're calling the method in a wrong place buddy :D

Comment: @Sharpedge So basically what I am getting is at index 0 = [Travel Standard, Fixed Standard] rather than them being broken down in their own individual index? I also did a print on the item count of the combo box and it turns out it is 1 strangely and that too gets printed out twice.

Comment: @Sharpedge Dude! almost there okay so basically the first item is [Travel Standard, Fixed Standard] as one option but I want them broken down into individual options. :D This is exciting! When I run the GUI I can see the first option in the combo box means almost there :D

Comment: I solved you "populating the JComboBox Question" upvote and accept my answer :) and then start a new question as how to break them .. I'll answer that separately ..

Comment: @Sharpedge Right I'll do that now. Thanks!

Comment: `cbox.addItem(strings);` won't work.  This is adding the `ArrayList` to the combobox as a single element, not the individual elements in the list.  Make a new `ComboBoxModel`, add the individual elements to it and then set the model to the combo box

Answer (score 3):

It might be that your `SELECT` query returns no results. To verify this, you can add logging statements inside the `while (rs.next())` loop. My SQL knowledge is a bit rusty, but I remember using `'` (single quotes) for string literals, whereas you use `"` (double quotes) in your statement.

Besides that, I see several things which could cause problems:

- The SQL code for `PreparedStatement` **should not** be created by string concatenation. Instead, use `?` for parameter values which will be substituted into the statement, e.g.

  ```
  stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Name FROM Discount WHERE Type = ?");
  stmt.setString(1, type); // first (and only) parameter
  rs = stmt.executeQuery();
  ```
- It is strongly recommended that you explicitly close JDBC resources after being done with them. For this, you need to add a `finally` block after the `catch (SQLException ...)`, e.g.

  ```
  } finally {
       try {
           if (rs != null) rs.close();
       } catch (SQLException ignore) {}

       try {
           if (stmt != null) stmt.close();
       } catch (SQLException ignore) {}

       try {
           if (conn != null) conn.close();
       } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
  }
  ```

  or, preferrably, use the `try-with-resources` statement (if you are using Java 7 and higher):

  ```
  try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(...)) {
      // ...
      try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Name FROM Discount WHERE Type = ?")) {
          // ...
          try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
              while (rs.next()) {
                  // processing
              }
          }
      }
  } catch (SQLException) {
      Logger....;
  } // notice no finally block; resources are closed automatically
  ```

Comment: Would you need to quote the parameter (`'?'`)?

Comment: Tried this all but it didn't work unfortunately. Double quotes do work for sql statements. I've done many other ones and all of them have worked fine but I have been populating JTables and text fields really and this is the first ever time I'm trying to populate a JComboBox.

Comment: @MadProgrammer no, quotes are not needed. Corrected my answer

Comment: @JP24 If you change your `while (rs.next())` loop body to this: `String name = rs.getString("Name"); Logger.getLogger(Model.class.getName()).warning(name);`, does it print anything? You should also try to step into the loop with debugger, to see if the loop body even executes once...

Answer (score 3):

When trying to add elements dynamically to a combo box, use `MutableComboBoxModel.addElement`

```
JComboBox box = new JComboBox(new DefaultComboBoxModel());
....
MutableComboBoxModel model = (DefaultComboBoxModel)box.getModel();
while (rs.next()) {
    model.addElement(rs.getString("Name"));
}
```

To remove all elements you could also do

```
((DefaultComboBoxModel)box.getModel).removeAllElements();
```

Using the model methods will fire the necessary changes to update the ui

Comment: Right when did a system.out on this and checked the value of each position of the jcombobox index. The values successfully printed. However now the problem lies in me actually seeing these when I run the GUI and when I click on the drop down box and I can't seem to see the values there. The jComboBox is blank. :S

Comment: Try using this and see what happens

Comment: Did that, but when I run the whole project and I click on the JComboBox nothing seems to appear, however when doing a system.out.print the values within the index of the model are successfully printed to the terminal.

Comment: If you have initial data you want shown in the combo box, then you need to add all your elements to the model to start.

Comment: Like `DefaultComboBoxModel(myDataArray)`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm really new to this stuff, can you explain more with the DefeaultComboBoxModel(myDataArray) thing please I'm confused :S.

Comment: The `DefaultComboBoxModel` is a just a data structure to hold the data of the combo box. So instead of passing your initial data straight to the combobox `new JComboBox(myDataArray)`, you will be passing it the `DefaultComboBoxModel` which is then passed to the `JComboBox` ie `new JComboBox(new DefaultComboBoxModel(myDataArray))`

Comment: You can obtain a reference to the `DefaultComboBoxModel` by using `cBox.getModel()`. And with the reference, you can use it's methods. The reason you want to use it is because it automatically update the ui when dynamically adding or removing elements, something `JComboBox.addItem` _doesn't_ do. Get it?

Comment: Right I understand and when I am passing my data structure would it be exactly just doing DefaultComboBoxModel(the array I'm passing here) literally?

Comment: Pretty much. _`"the array I'm passing here"`_ is the initial data for the combo box. After that, you never have to do it again. Just manipulate the `DefaultComboBoxModel` with its methods like `removeAllElements` and `addElement`