# How to break down individual values in JComboBox?

Tags: java, sql, swing, jcombobox

Here is my code that sets the values in the `JComboBox`:

```
 public void setDiscountNames(String type, JComboBox cbox) {

    cbox.removeAllItems();

    ArrayList<Discount> names = new ArrayList<Discount>();
    try {        
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abpp034?user=abpp034&password=120001772");



       stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Name FROM Discount WHERE Type = \"" + type + "\"");
       rs = stmt.executeQuery();



       List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(rs.next()){

        strings.add(rs.getString("Name"));  // Confirm if "Name" is valid


}
        cbox.addItem(strings);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Model.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

}

Here is where I call the method and set the combo box with the values:

```
   public DiscountGUIView() {
    initComponents();
    model.setDiscountNames("Fixed", jComboBox1);



}
```

Now the problem is I am getting this in my combo box `[Travel Standard, Fixed Standard]` exactly as this when I click on my combo box.

Though I want it them to be split apart in their own index without the "[" and "]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cbox.addItem(strings);` is adding the `List` as single element to the `JComboBox`.

As you have [previously been advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519982/how-to-populate-data-in-a-jcombobox), you should add the values to a `ComboBoxModel`, for example...

```
DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
try {        
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abpp034?user=abpp034&password=120001772");

    stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Name FROM Discount WHERE Type = \"" + type + "\"");
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()){
        model.addElement(rs.getString("Name"));
    }

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Model.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} 
cbox.setModel(model);
```

Take a look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more details

You may also want to take a look at [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) as you are not using them properly...which was also highlighted in your previous question...

As you have previously been advised, you should be closing your resources to the database when you are done with them, failing to do so could impare you databases performance...

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {        
    //...
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Model.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} finally {
    try {
        rs.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
    try {
        stmt.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
    try {
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
}
```

Or if you're using Java 7

```
try (Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abpp034?user=abpp034&password=120001772")){        
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Name FROM Discount WHERE Type = \"" + type + "\"")) {
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery) {
            //...
        } catch (SQLException exp) {
            Logger.getLogger(Model.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } catch (SQLException exp) {
        Logger.getLogger(Model.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Model.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: +1, but could be very important, not joke, cbox.setModel(model); should be executed after finally { ended

Comment: @mKorbel That's a fair point, but would also depend on what the OP wanted to achieve when an error occurs...

Answer (score 2):

```
 List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
 while(rs.next()){
     strings.add(rs.getString("Name"));  // Confirm if "Name" is valid
 }
 cbox.addItem(strings);
```

You're only adding *one* item the combo box, which is the `List strings`. A List as a string *will* be `[something, something, something]` as you are experiencing.

You need to add the items individually, preferably using the the model of the combobox (as MadProgrammer points out in his answer, and I also pointed out in [your last post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22520520/2587435)) and not the combo box directly.

Comment: Oh I remember this now. Damn I forgot this. It's like python where you have an array of strings and Haskell ahh right.