# Java add combobox in JTable in for loop

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I have a table that displays the data: ID, NAME, CATEGORY, COMPANY. Data is retrieved from the database. I would like to add a ComboBox to the column CATEGORY. So as to be able to choose any category that they are in the database.

```
List<Item> item;
JTable itemTable = new JTable();
JScrollPane itemScroll = new JScrollPane();
DefaultTableModel itemmodel = new DefaultTableModel();

        itemmodel.setRowCount(0);
        item = model.getItem();

        for (Item ite : item) {
            itemmodel.addRow(new Object[] { ite.getId(), ite.getName(),
                    ite.getCategory(), ite.getCompany() });
        }
        item.clear();
```

Then I add the data to the JFrame properly and everything displays. I read the documentation, but I do not know how to use the examples in my case.

To display the same categories have separate jTable and data downloading via

```
        tablemodel.setRowCount(0);
        category = model.getCategory();

        for (Category cat: categoryList) {
            tablemodel
                    .addRow(new Object[] { cat.getId(), cat.getName() });
        }
        categoryList.clear();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it this way and it looks great. Is this the solution is correct? How do I store category id in Combobox?

```
        itemmodel.setRowCount(0);
        item = model.getItem();

        people = model.getCategory();

        for (Category cate : categoryList) {
            categoryBox.addItem(cate.getName());
        }
        for (Item ite : item) {
            itemmodel.addRow(new Object[] { ite.getId(),ite.getName(),  
                    ite.getCategory(), ite.getCompany() });
        }
        item.clear();

        TableColumn categoryColumn = itemTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
        categoryColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(categoryBox));
```

Comment: `DefaultComboBoxModel` can hold arbitrary elements characterized by a generic type parameter; you can change the displayed name as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25432381/230513).

Comment: Ok, but I change addItem to `companyBox.addItem(new Company(comp.getId(), comp.getName(), null));` and I just call in my ActionListener for ComboBox `Category selected_category = (Category) categoryBox.getSelectedItem();`

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch the categories from the database using the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2531942/230513) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519982/230513). You can specify the resulting `JComboBox` as a table column's `CellEditor` using the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513).