# Add an object to a JComboBox but show a string without overriding the object's .toString() method

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, tostring

The object class that I am working with already has its `.toString()` method overridden, giving its name. But I am using same object in a `JComboBox` and I need to display another String. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Insufficeint data for answering..Post your code..

Comment: Companies like Microsoft and Apple spend millions of dollars to create usable UI's. I'm curious, why did you accept the solution that breaks the functionality of the combo box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You bet there is! What you want to do is to give your JComboBox a custom cell renderer.

To do this, you could extending DefaultListCellRenderer making sure to override its `getListCellRendererComponent(...)` method. Once you've done this, you would call `setRenderer(...)` on your JComboBox, passing in an object of your new class.

For more on this, please be sure to check out the [renderer section of the JComboBox tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer).

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/).

If you just use a custom renderer you will break the default functionality of the combo box that allows the user to select an item using the keyboard. The user should be able to use the mouse or keyboard when using a GUI.

The above solution shows how to implement the `KeySelectionManager` so you retain this default functionality.